# kernel memory grows creating files in ubuntu in a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

Creating files in a ubuntu container (also other distributions) causes the kernel memory grows. The memory do not decreases except when the files are deleted.
Is it the expected behavior ? The memory does not decrease when the process that creates files stops.

It is very easy to reproduce.

- Create a docker instance with a volume from the latest ubuntu image
- Log in the instance and create files inside that volume with this command : `for i in {1..100000}; do dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4096 count=1 of=file$i; done`
- Look at the file /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes

The kmem is going to grow.
I need to understand why, to avoid or mitigate this behavior in the case of a program that do the same: create a set of files

Comment: Seems like it could be caching - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82820/force-dd-not-to-cache-or-not-to-read-from-cache

Comment: I tested again caching and no caching and the kernel memory grows in both cases. Looking at /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.kmem.slabinfo , the values that grows are fuse_inode and dentry. It sounds logic that those values grow creating files

Comment: But I expect those objects be released after those files are closed

Answer (score 0):

We found that the problem are the **dentry** and **inodes** caches.
It is possible to set the parameter vfs_cache_pressure using sysctl.

The documentation is here : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

### **vfs_cache_pressure**

This percentage value controls the tendency of the kernel to reclaim
the memory which is used for caching of directory and inode objects.

At the default value of vfs_cache_pressure=100 the kernel will attempt to
reclaim dentries and inodes at a "fair" rate with respect to pagecache and
swapcache reclaim.  Decreasing vfs_cache_pressure causes the kernel to prefer
to retain dentry and inode caches. When vfs_cache_pressure=0, the kernel will
never reclaim dentries and inodes due to memory pressure and this can easily
lead to out-of-memory conditions. Increasing vfs_cache_pressure beyond 100
causes the kernel to prefer to reclaim dentries and inodes.

Increasing vfs_cache_pressure significantly beyond 100 may have negative
performance impact. Reclaim code needs to take various locks to find freeable
directory and inode objects. With vfs_cache_pressure=1000, it will look for
ten times more freeable objects than there are.